# passing parameters from a windows batch script into a powershell script

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, powershell, parameters

I have a powershell script which uses 'quser' command to extract data regarding users logged onto a series of terminal servers.

I want to add a timestamp to the output files, this timestamp variable is created in a windows batch file which then calls the powershell script passes the computername and timestamp, but the powershell script is erroring with 'Missing ')' in function parameter list'

```
    param(
[CmdletBinding()] 
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
           ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[string[]]$ComputerName = 'localhost'
[string[]]$timestamp <========= this is the line I have added
)
```

If I remove my added line (marked in the code above), the script runs fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a comma between the parameters:

```
param(
[CmdletBinding()] 
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
           ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[string[]]$ComputerName = 'localhost',
[string[]]$timestamp
)
```

Also unless you want multiple timestamps you probably just want it to be a string rather than a string array (so `[string]$timestamp`).

The error message I get looks like this (except that it is in red). The first error points at the end of the localhost line then there is a knock-on error for what by that time seems to be a spurious `)`:

```
PS C:\>     param(
>> [CmdletBinding()]
>> [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
>>            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
>> [string[]]$ComputerName = 'localhost'
>> [string[]]$timestamp
>> )
>>
At line:5 char:38
+ [string[]]$ComputerName = 'localhost'
+                                      ~
Missing ')' in function parameter list.
At line:7 char:1
+ )
+ ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInFunctionParameterList
```

I'm using Powershell 3 here. Other versions may show the error differently.

Comment: No problem. BTW the error message should have shown you the line with localhost and a `~` under where the problem was (i.e. where the comma was missing). Or if you use ISE to edit the script it shows a red `~` underline in the editor where the error is.

Comment: didnt see that - this is the whole message - 'Missing ')' in function parameter list.
At C:\ts_users\Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1:35 char:5
+      <<<< [string]$timestamp
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (CloseParenToken:TokenId) [], Paren
   tContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInFunctionParameterList', I suppose the <<<< was indicating where the error was

Comment: @nyehus, I've added the message I see to the end of my answer. I'm using Powershell 3.0 so perhaps you are using an older version and they maybe improved the error messages.